# Does try with resources execute finally block before catch?

Tags: java, try-catch, java-7, try-with-resources

I learned java 7 feature `try with resources`.

In catch block I should handle exceptions from `try`(as usually) and from `finally`

Does it mean that finally was invoked before catch? What if I want to treat to Closeable resource in catch?

There is one observation, which confirms my assumption.

If try block throw exception1 and close method of resource throws exception2 then exception1 will catched and exception2 will supressed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What if I want to treat to Closeable resource in catch?

Resources declared in the `try` part have their scope restricted to the `try` body. If you need access to them in the `catch`, use a regular `try-catch` statement.

The `finally` block will always execute last.

Comment: **The finally block will always execute last.** you are about explicit finally. generated finally executes before explicit catch

Comment: @gstackoverflow In that case, yes.

Comment: @gstackoverflow That's known as an [_extended `try-with-resources`_](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3.2).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I would be good to put the extended try-with-resources link in the answer. That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks!